# No ParameterStore access with sub path definition

Tags: aws-policies, aws-parameter-store

I have the following policy in place which works fine on any parameter within `/network/testnet/*`

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "ssm:DescribeParameters"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "ssm:GetParameters",
                "ssm:GetParameter",
                "ssm:GetParametersByPath"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:ssm:eu-central-1:xx:parameter/network/*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

but as soon as I want to restrict the resource to `arn:aws:ssm:eu-central-1:xx:parameter/network/testnet/*` it does no longer allow access to any of the parameters within `/network/testnet/*`.

My lambda function then gets the following error

```
"errorType": "Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection",
    "errorMessage": "AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::xxx:assumed-role/dsome-app/some-function is not authorized to perform: ssm:GetParametersByPath on resource: arn:aws:ssm:eu-central-1:xxx:parameter/network/testnet because no identity-based policy allows the ssm:GetParametersByPath action",
```

Specifically I use CloudFormation and define access like that

```
Policies:
      - SSMParameterReadPolicy:
          ParameterName: "network/testnet/*"
```

Are restriction to sub paths not allowed or what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do dynamoose.model('example_user', schema, {"create": false}) to get away from the need to create a table https://dynamoosejs.com/guide/Model/